# Analysing the complexity of a git repository's history

Tags: git, metrics

I am sure most developers are familiar with cyclomatic complexity which is used to indicate the complexity of code.

I was wondering if there is a tool that analyses the complexity of git history. Not the actual code or commits themselves but how the commit graph looks.

Something like having a "clean" history would give a low score and having a complex history would give a high score.

Any ideas if this exists?

Comment: What do you define as 'clean'? In larger organizations using many branches and forks for careful and well-defined merges is highly recommended, while the 'clean' approach of dumping everything into master results in chaos

Comment: @AndrewFan that's a fair point. For me a "clean" structure is basically favouring rebasing a feature branch onto master, possibly squashing commits, before merging. I've seen it referred to as "linear" or "semi-linear" merge.

Comment: It may be possible to approach this problem in the [manner in which graph complexity is typically analysed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239652/measure-graph-complexity), but this kind of analysis is far from trivial, and it may be that people haven't yet found it worthwhile to create a tool to perform such analysis

Comment: That being said, you may find it possible to create a tool to perform rudimentary complexity analysis, simply by measuring quite basic information such as size of commits, or average number of parents per commit

Comment: @OliverRadini Thanks for the ideas! I'll definitely give those a shot.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to get all your branches, generate all combination of two branches, and for each couple test if one branch is contained into the other (`git branch --contains`). If that is the case, then you can increment a counter. At the end, you can provide a score, that would be the counter divided by the number of combination:

- A score close to 100% likely means that all your branches are merged one into the other
- A score closes to 50% means that all your branches are probably all merged into master
- A score of 0% means that your changes are systematically rebased (or that all your branches are un active).

This is quiet limited, but there is a code sample [here](https://github.com/gcattan/git-quality-check) on Github with an [example](https://github.com/gcattan/git-quality-check/blob/master/.github/workflows/test-action.yml) of how to integrate it into your repo.